# What is the length of GH?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

What is the length of GH?

[image]

Can you help me?
I personally believe that this can't be solved?

Comment: From a [standard theorem about circles,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) we have $(CH)(CG)=(12)(12)$.

Comment: The standard theorem I believe @AndréNicolas is referring to is [Power of a Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point).

Comment: Not that the "standard theorem" can be proved by showing that the triangles $CBH$ and $CGB$ are similar - and this can also be used for a direct proof here even if the theorem is not known.

Comment: You are welcome to see my hints given in problem #344557

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Use the formula for the tangent-chord relationship. The formula is $a^2=b(b+c)$, where $a=\text{tangent length}$, $b=\text{exterior chord length}$, and $c=\text{interior chord length}$. Then solve for $x$.